# JavaScript DOM: html table manipulation issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="inventoryItems" id="inventoryItems">
    <tr>
        <th id="itemCost" class="noLeft">id </th>
        <th id="soldAmount" class="right">Item Description    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itemRow">
        <th >
            <input onBlur="shapeMapper(this)" ></input>
        </th>
        <th >
            <input onBlur="shapeMapper(this)" ></input>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just a really simple table,
and I am trying to manipulate it with JavaScript of the following form:

```
function shapeMapper(arg){
    //arg goes unused for now.
    var tblName = "inventoryItems";
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tblName);
    var soldAmount = document.getElementById("soldAmount").cellIndex;
    var itemCost = document.getElementById("itemCost").cellIndex;
    var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;
    var itemList = "";
    var totalCost=0;
    var totalSold=0;

    for(var i = 1; i<=rowCount-1 ; i++){
        var fC = tbl.rows[i].cells[itemCost].firstChild;
        r=tbl.rows[i];

        alert(r.cells[itemCost].value);
        totalCost = totalCost + Number(r.cells[itemCost].firstChild.value) ; 
        totalSold = totalSold + Number(r.cells[soldAmount].firstChild.value) ;
    }
}
```

but `r.cells[itemCost].firstChild.value` even when there is  value typed into the inputbox comes back as "undefined"...does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: proper indentation next time. no one's going to solve a problem when the problem itself can't be read.

Comment: Readability is relative....not a baseline for judgement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
r.cells[itemCost].firstElementChild.value
```

otherwise it gets a `textElement` of undefined value, because spaces and carriage returns are considered as nodes in the DOM. `firstChild` gets the first *node* child, while `firstElementChild` gets the first *element* child.

However, be aware that `firstElementChild` is not supported on every browser (FF < 3.5, IE < 9).

Comment: The `undefined` value is what you get when the value has not been defined. This is most commonly expecting a certain member to exist, in this case `value`, when it does not. Try `console.log(r.cells[itemCost])` (obviously you need a browser that implements window.console(), or firefox+firebug) in order to get a view of the data structure present there if your client code is not responsible for creating it. (+1)

Comment: perfect. thanks so much this is exactly it! it makes perfect sense now.